# How to strore URL in keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, keychain

I wanted to store the URL in device keychain which is used to point device to specific server. When application launch first time it will store URL in keychain.

Comment: Why in the keychain? Is this URL private data? If you just need to persist data, there are much better places to store it.

Comment: please suggest other ways

Comment: NSUserDefaults is the most obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITextField *url = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 30, 240, 30)];
[url setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestAppData" accessGroup:nil];
```

Writing to the Keychain-

// Store URL to keychain

```
Nsstring *strURL=@"abcd" 
[keychain setObject:strURL forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

Reading from the Keychain-

// Get AcessToken from keychain (if it exists)

```
[url setText:[keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount]];
```

Notes:
Writing and retrieving values from the keychain doesn’t seem to work in the simulator.
Uninstalling an application will not remove the items from the keychain. If you run the demo application on your device, and uninstall the app, the username and password will remain in the keychain (a firmware reset will, of course, remove the keychain values).

Comment: Nikita, Appreciate with your answer. But while you deal with account information at that time we are use "kSecAttrAccount". For the same if we use some other information we used "kSecValueData". You can go through in detail so used batter way.

Comment: thanks Nikita Khandelwal but i have already storing key and value using kSecAttrAccount and kSecValueData.is there any other key to store url ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Vinayak,

There is number of key user related to it's type. Please find below.

```
kSecAttrAccessGroup         -       CFStringRef
kSecAttrCreationDate        -       CFDateRef
kSecAttrModificationDate    -       CFDateRef
kSecAttrDescription         -       CFStringRef
kSecAttrComment             -       CFStringRef
kSecAttrCreator             -       CFNumberRef
kSecAttrType                -       CFNumberRef
kSecAttrLabel               -       CFStringRef
kSecAttrIsInvisible         -       CFBooleanRef
kSecAttrIsNegative          -       CFBooleanRef
kSecAttrAccount             -       CFStringRef
kSecAttrService             -       CFStringRef
kSecAttrGeneric             -       CFDataRef
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be store it in a plist file